# How many Gs would a driver of the Bugatti Veyron experience on the Ehra-Lessien track when cornering before record attempt?

Tags: classical-mechanics, centrifugal-force, everyday-life

Apologies if too specific.

Watched a documentary [National Geographic Megafactories Bugatti Veyron](http://natgeotv.com/nl/mega-factories-2/videos/bugatti-veyron)

I told an colleague (engineer) about the need to warm the car up and then unleash it on the long stretch to be able to make it to 405km/h and mused that the curve before the straight probably had to be taken at 250km/h to do so. He immediately replied that the G-force of going around a(ny) curve at 250km/h would kill the driver... I find that very hard to believe but do not have the skills nor knowledge to refute it. It would be cool to get him this app http://www.dynolicious.com/ and a trip in a Veyron ;)

Here is the [Ehra-Lessien track](http://googlesightseeing.com/2007/03/super-secret-volkswagen-test-track/)  and here is the [actual curve](http://googlesightseeing.com/maps?p=&c=&t=k&hl=en&ll=52.595202,10.787587&z=16) where some of the clever people here could glean the radius - I think 350m

Can someone show some math and a graph or so?

I have been looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_One_car#Lateral_force

> Turn 8 at the Istanbul Park circuit, a
>   190° relatively tight 4-apex corner,
>   in which the cars maintain speeds
>   between 265 and 285 km/h (165 and 177
>   mph) (in 2006) and experience between
>   4.5g and 5.5g for 7 seconds—the longest sustained hard cornering in
>   Formula 1.

which supports my claim - but would love some more information on this specific matter

Here is a link on what an [Apex means in motoring](http://www.drivingfast.net/techniques/racing-line.htm)
And here are some [formulas](http://forums.autosport.com/lofiversion/index.php/t53791.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neglecting friction, the force experienced is the [Centrifugal Force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_force) $F=\frac{mv^2}{r}$ (it would be less if you included friction since the car actually slips) vectorially added to the orthogonal gravitational force $F_g=mg$, i.e. $F = m\sqrt{\left(\frac{v^2}r\right)^2 + g^2}$ where $g = 9.81 \frac{m}{s^2}$<sup>1</sup>. Divide this by $F_g$ to obtain a result in Gs. Remember to use SI-units, i.e. divide a km/h speed by 3.6 (1000 km/m / 3600 s/h) to obtain m/s.

For the 350 m curve and 285 km/h that yields about 2.08 gs only, to obtain the 5.5 gs mentioned a radius of about 118 m is required, or some higher velocity (490 km/h for the 350 m curve).

<sup>1)</sup> Thanks [J.H.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/394/j-h) for this important correction!

Comment: Thanks - to get to 400km/h on the stretch they would then be able to go at 350km/h around - how much g for how long to go 180 deg with r=350m?

Comment: @mplungjan Wait - to get total g's experienced by the driver you should include the downards force too, so in this case the g's are (1+1.83^2)^0.5=2.09g

Comment: @J.H. that's absolutely correct, thanks for your correction

Comment: Banked corner, or does the Veyron produce some pretty significant downforce at those speeds?  On (race) tires alone, no downforce, flat corner, a performance car will typically max out at *around* 1.3g continuous).